# Reading from file C programing

Tags: c, unix

I'd appreciate any help I can get. I'm not sure I completely understand this program. I also get the following errors when I try to run it.
I was also told that on line 15 I was trying to mod a char array. What should I be doing? Thanks for taking a look.

```
structFinal.c: In function print_part':
structFinal.c:14: error: invalid operands to binary %
structFinal.c: In function main':
structFinal.c:36: error: syntax error before ']' token


#include <stdio.h>
#define NAME_LEN 25

typedef struct {
    int number;
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    int on_hand;
} part;

void print_part(part p[], int ind) {
    int i;
    printf("Whole List\n");
    for(i = 0; i< ind; i++)
    {
        if(p[ind].name % 2 == 0)
          printf("Part number: %d\n", p[ind].number);
        printf("Part name: %s\n", p[ind].name);
        if(p[ind].on_hand < 5)
           printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", p[ind].on_hand);
    }

printf("%d\n", p[ind].number);
fgets(p[ind].name,50,fp);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &p[ind].on_hand);
printf("%s\n----%d\n", p[ind].name, p[ind].on_hand);
ind++;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &p[ind].number);
 a = fgetc(fp);
} print_part(p[ ] , ind);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

**Edit:** I just tried this on my Ubuntu machine in Netbeans and it ran. We're suppose to run this in *Unix* and that's were it fails. I'm lost.

Edit: This is my final file so far. I'm pretty sure this works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NAME_LEN 25

typedef struct {
    int number;
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    int on_hand;
} part;

void print_part(part p[], int ind) {
int i;
printf("Whole List\n");
for(i = 0; i< ind; i++)
{
printf("Part number: %d\n", p[i].number);
printf("Part name: %s\n", p[i].name);
printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", p[i].on_hand);
 }
 }

int main() {
/* first try, input only one set and print it */
part p[50];
int ind=0;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("structTest.txt", "r");

fscanf(fp, "%d", &p[ind].number);

char a;
a = fgetc(fp); /* extract the return symbol out of input buffer */
while (p[ind].number != 0)
{
     while (a != '\n')
     {
             a = fgetc(fp);
    }

    printf("%d\n", p[ind].number);
    fgets(p[ind].name,50,fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &p[ind].on_hand);
    printf("%s\n----%d\n", p[ind].name, p[ind].on_hand);
    ind++;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &p[ind].number);
     a = fgetc(fp);
}
print_part(p , ind);
fclose(fp);
 return 0;
}
```

/*
   the code is fixed so it will extact all white spaces after a part number
   is typed. the getchar while loop will keep get one character to var a
   until a return key is reached
*/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please format your code correctly.

Comment: You haven't even pasted 52 lines of code, so how are we supposed to help you find the `]` on line 52?

Comment: Those two lines looks a little weird:
if(p[ind].name % 2 == 0)`
printf("Part number: %d\n", p[ind].number);`
Look at the last char...

Comment: `p[ind].name` is of type `char[26]` you can only use the modulus operator (`%`) on integers.

Comment: @Skaarjasaurus thanks, I hadn't noticed the back tics were there. I took them out. That was just bad editing from a reddit post.

Comment: @Wooble I corrected the line numbers to approximate the lines I actually posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some character at the end. Notices this **`** which doesn't belong there?

```
if(p[ind].name % 2 == 0)`
```

And this

```
print_part(p[ ] , ind);
```

should be

```
print_part(p , ind);
```

Answer (score 1):

p[ind].name is a characters array, you cannot run modulu operation on it.

You can run % on numbers - integers.

What would a logical meaning be of doing module on a string? (char array)

Say you have the array contents of abcde what is abcde % 2?